# Jmeter Perfmon plugin not working with parameter 'Process Name'

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have added a parameter CPU 'name=chrome#' for checking my chrome CPU usage however, I am getting only the total CPU Usage.[image]

> Note: I have added both Chrome and Total CPU but both looks same

Comment: I have already tried that but getting the same statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your operating system you might need to change it to:

- `chrome.exe` - for MS Windows family
- `Google Chrome` - for MacOS

[image]

So I would recommend determining the exact process name using process monitoring software for your operating system and amend the metric accordingly. Also given you don't see the second chart take a look at [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) log file or [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) - it should contain some clues.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information on using PerfMon plugin.

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks for the help Dmitri. However, I could see more than one instances of chrome in my taskmanager process list. Is Perfmon taking the aggregate CPU use or for a single instance for chrome. Please confirm

Comment: Also in your above image, Chrome CPU usage (Blue line in the graph) is going beyond the Total CPU usage (Red Line). How is that possible as the Red one should be the aggregate of all the process?